# Not able to login between two EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I created two EC2 instance under same subnet, using the same key and same security group. Only machine1 is attached to public ip. I also added outbound ssh access from the same security group. I am able to login to one Instance(Machine1) with my private key using putty from my laptop. Now from Machine1 if I use ssh to login to Machine2 with below command  `ssh ec2-user@secondmachine-privateip`, I am getting error saying Permisssion denied (publickey). Tried various options and not getting clue on what I am missing.

while giving -v option in above command gave the following verbose. I have not generated any new key or added any file at .ssh folder.

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.0.0.xx [10.0.0.140] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA a5:d7:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
debug1: Host 'xx.xx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: -v option while giving above command gave the following verbose. I have not generated any new key or added any file at .ssh folder.

Comment: Output of `ssh-add -l`?

Comment: I am getting following error. "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am in. I have setup the authentication agent pageant in windows.